# Why is the ledmac line number misaligned with the final item?

Tags: lists, vertical-alignment, itemize, line-numbering, ledmac

Here's a minimal document showing the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ledmac}

\begin{document}

\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\begin{itemize}
\item This item aligns with the line number...
\item ... but the line number is far below this item.
\end{itemize}
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

The document turns out like this:

```
1 · This item aligns with the line number...
  · ... but the line number is far below this item.
2
```

Note that:

a) it's always the *last* item in a list,

b) the line *is* aligned if you add a newline (`\\`) at the end of the last item (but you get another line number, which looks odd),

c) the line *is* aligned if you add text between `\end{itemize}` and `\pend`,

d) and the line is *not* aligned if you simply add text after `\pend`.

So why does this happen and how can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the

```
\beginnumbering
\pstart
...
\pend
\endnumbering
```

block *inside* the `itemize` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ledmac}

\begin{document}

\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\begin{itemize}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\item This item aligns with the line number...
\item ... but the line number is far below this item.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I am astonished; after reading the comments to my answer, I was doing some tests and now the following example code (which is basically the same as the example code in the question) compiles OK and behaves as expected!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ledmac}

\begin{document}

text text text text text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text  text text text
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\begin{itemize}
\item This item aligns with the line number...
\item This item also aligns with the line number...
\end{itemize}
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

I'll investigate what is going on!

EDIT2: Finally I discovered what's going on, but I don't know the reason behind the problem... it seems like a bug in `ledmac`. The problem is related to the length of the text in each item. You can see this with the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ledmac}

\begin{document}

\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\begin{itemize}
\item This item aligns with the line number...
\item This item also aligns ...
\item This doesn't ... % but it will align if you add this text
\end{itemize}
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Compile the example as it is and you will see the strange behaviour described in the question; here's an image of the result:

[image]

Now, delete the comment character and compile again and you will get the expected result:

[image]

The same strange results will be observed if enough text is added to the second item of the example code in the question.

I think you should write a note to the package creators.

Comment: True.  But it also introduces a *horizontal* alignment problem.  If you look at the output of your example, you will see there is very little space between the line number and the bullet point.  Add a bit of text before the `itemize` environment to convince yourself that it's a problem.

Comment: Also, I tested moving `\pstart` and `\pend` inside the environment, which still had the horizontal alignment issue.  Moving the `\beginnumbering` and `\endnumbering` has an additional problem of resetting the numbering at the start of the `itemize` environment, which I don't want.

Comment: @Jon Ericson: I've updated my answer with a (surprisingly) working example. I'll try to determine what is happening.

Comment: I'm seeing that too.  But I can't grok what the difference is nor apply the answer to my (very) non-minimal document.  I wonder if it has something to do with what's written to the `.aux` or `.1` or `.end` files?

Comment: And to answer my own question: no.  I created two separate test files with the only difference being the content of the second item and I can't figure out why the alignment gets screwed up in the original and not your version.  They should be the same!

Comment: @Jon Ericson: yes, I also did some tests deleting all the auxiliary files, but that has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @Jon Ericson: found it! I'll update my answer in a few minutes. It seems like a bug in ledmac.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Gonzalo Medina's excellent (and accepted) answer, I've sent Peter Wilson, the author of the `ledmac` package, an email explaining the problem.  If and when there's a bug fix, I'll update this answer with the details.

In addition, his answer guided me to a temporary workaround for the test case in the question without printing bogus text to extend the line.  Use the `\phantom` macro:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item This item aligns with the line number...
\item ... and the line number is not below this item.\phantom{extra text to pad the line}
\end{itemize}
```

The result is:

```
1 · This item aligns with the line number...
2 · ... and the line number is not below this item.
```